# How do i fix css not loading

Tags: python, html, css

When i run my Web app the html loads but the style.css doesn't what should i do? Well

I Tried to change the style.css to another folder but didn't work please Give me some answers

I also use Flask for my web app

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then 
read [what kind of questions you can ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and 
[what kind of questions you should not ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). The question as of now has no value to the community and can not be answered. There so many potencial issues incl 404 error (wrong pathing, wrong, file structure, typo...), 403 error (missing read permission)... Do the devtools of your browser output any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <!-- Favicon-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css_image/asdf.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Responsive navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <div class="container px-lg-5">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Griffincode</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Header-->
        <header class="py-5">
            <div class="container px-lg-5">
                <div class="p-4 p-lg-5 bg-light rounded-3 text-center">
                    <div class="m-4 m-lg-5">
                        <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold">A warm welcome!</h1>
                        <p class="fs-4">Bootstrap utility classes are used to create this jumbotron since the old component has been removed from the framework. Why create custom CSS when you can use utilities?</p>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#!">Call to action</a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Here is some of my html code that i posted here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that you have respected the project layout as described in the [official Docs of flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/layout/)?

Please make sure your style.css is within the **static** folder. Refer to this tree below:

```
├── project/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── index.html
│   └── static/
│       └── styles
|          ├── style.css
```

Comment: Well i have a Main.py and then a templates folder with my index.html and then a css folder outside the templates folder yeah pretty much like this setup there

Comment: Did you link your .css file as well into your .html page? This may be the correct syntax of doing so: `<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/style.css') }}">`

Comment: should i add it under: <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->

Comment: Would you please add more code to your main question so I can get more context?

Comment: @tacoshy I did not ask for any upvote. I asked for the answer to be pinned for future references to anyone who may face a similar problem.

Comment: @tacoshy I do not understand the reasoning behind not reminding the person who asks the question to pin the answer as an "Accepted answer" for future references. I would have done the same even if it wasn't my answer, since I believe that it is a good practice. In other words, if it is the correct answer, why shouldn't OP mark it as such?

Comment: yes but you should not remind the OP or ask any of that. It is equivalent to asking for reputation. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it

Comment: Referring to the link you have mentioned: `So following up with a comment like "Please close your question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you most" is a public service message in my book. Strictly a comment.` is exactly what I have said. New users sometimes have hard times figuring out how SO works, so it is just fine to remind them to close their questions when they get an answer. If by doing so, the person who wrote the answer get some reputation, then good for them.

Comment: yes but not below your answer but below the question. However like I said, there is no reason to ask this, as this question obviosly does not meet the guidelines and will be removed. Also a reason why your comment was deleted by a moderator already. The overall harm in upvoting or checking answers in question that do not meet the guidelines outweight the short time you get some reputation. As said, assson as the question will be removed (can happen within a few days) you will lose the reputation anyway.